# Question about independence.

Tags: probability

There are $N$ independent random variables $X=(X_1,\dots,X_N)$. We define $N$ events $E_1(X)$, $E_N(X)$. The probability of each event is $Pr[E_n(X)]=p$. Therefore the probability the event $E_n(X)$ does not happen is $1-p$ where $n\in \{1,\dots, N \}$. Can we say in average out of the $N$ events, $pN$ number of events occur?

My attempt: If the events $E_1(X)$, $\dots$ $E_N(X)$ were independent then I can make a binomial distribution from them, with probability of success $p$. That is $N$ trials of  random variable $X$ which has two values $X=1$ if $E_n(X)$ happens if not $X=0$.  But I'm not sure if the events are independent $E_1(X)$, $\dots$ $E_N(X)$  because each event depends on all $N$ independent random variables. Then can we at least say that the expected number of events that happen is **at  least**  $pN$?

Comment: You would actually want to look at using the multinomial distribution here, rather than the binomial distribution. The binomial distribution relies on there being two events, not $n$ events.

Comment: But there is only two events, $E_n(X)$ happens and $E_n(X)$ does not happen? thanks

Comment: The binomial distribution captures the binary string problem. Either $X_{1}$ happened or it didn't. So you could use a binary tuple to represent successes on various trials. So $(1, 0, 1, 1)$ represents successes on trials 1, 3, and 4. You have $N$ events, so you have more than two characters. You have $N+1$ characters. So suppose you have two possible events, and neither can occur. Then you're dealing with $\{0, 1, 2\}$. The multinomial distribution captures this better than the binomial distribution.

Comment: But I divide the space in to two cases, the event happens and the event does not happen like $A$ and compliment $A^c$. thanks.

Comment: So how do you deal with $E_{1}$ happening but $E_{2}$ not happening? So on a time unit, do you have at most a single event occur? If so, then you don't have independence. What about multiple events on the same time unit? Can you have repeated events at the same time unit? These are questions you don't deal with in the binomial distribution, but must deal with when using a multinomial distribution. A binomial distribution is like a coin flip. In how many ways can I get exactly three heads on five flips? Multinomial asks, given the word MISSISSIPPI, how many ways can I get SSSSIIIIPPM?

Comment: I think Uniwisdom's answer is correct. Do you think so too? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the binomial distribution here since the events $E_n(\mathbf{X})$ are not independent - they all depend on the same random vector $\mathbf{X}$.  However, that does not matter when considering the expected number of events that occur: linearity of expectation does not depend on independence so you get
$$
E\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N}E_{n}(\mathbf{X})\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}E\left[E_{n}(\mathbf{X})\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{N}p=Np.$$